# Right Click Div with Onclick Event Doesn't Display Link Options in Context Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I would like to make an entire div clickable.

Adding a onclick event to a div, does not allow me to do the following with the link:

1. Right Click -> Open Link in New Tab.
2. Right Click -> Copy Link Location.
3. Mouse Wheel Click to open link in new tab.
4. When hovering over the link, it shows the link's URL in the status bar.

As I understand HTML5, you should not wrap a div tag with a anchor tag. So I've added an onclick event to go to a new URL. However, I have the four problems I mentioned above.

```
    Good Example:
    <div onclick="location.href='http://www.google.com';">
        <p>Paragraph</p>
        <div>More content...</div>
    </div>
```

If I wrap the Div in an anchor tag, it has all of the functionality I would expect, but does not conform to HTML5 standards.

```
    Bad Example:
    <a href='http://www.google.com'>
        <div>
            <p>Paragraph</p>
            <div>More content...</div>
        </div>
    </a>
```

Is there an acceptable way of getting the behavior from the bad example using an onclick event like the good example?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="dv">
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    <div>More content...</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#dv').mousedown(function (event) {
switch (event.which) {
case 1: //Left Click
window.open('http://www.google.com');
case 2: //Middle Click
window.open('http://www.google.com');
break;
case 3: //Right Click
}
});
$("#dv").hover(function () {
window.status = "http://www.google.com";
});
});
```

An info about using `window.status`

> This property does not work in default configuration of Firefox and some other browsers: setting window.status has no effect on the text displayed in the status bar. To allow scripts to change the the status bar text, the user must set the dom.disable_window_status_change preference to false in the about:config screen.

Refrence: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.status